# Mysite signin repeats in IE

Tags: 2010, my-site, forms-authentication

For some reason my claimsbased mysite hosts won't let me login - it authenticates my credentials, but instead of taking me to mysite, it just refreshes the login page?

It only does this in IE - I get right through with Chrome.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I am experiencing a similar issue. Have you found a solution for yours?

Comment: @MikhailSP no solution found. Abandoned the project :/

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure the site address is added to the Local Intranet zone within the Security tab in Internet Options for IE. Also, there should be a check box on your Claims login page that says something like "Keep me logged in automatically" - try that as well.

Comment: Tried both, no luck - thanks though