# MySites, users cant get recognized

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, my-site, user-profile-service

I found this link [Mysite signin repeats in IE](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29399/mysite-signin-repeats-in-ie) that sounds like the problem I am having right now, but none of the answers is the right solution for me.

I have created MySites on Port 80 (I got two webapps at 80, mysites and my portal) and created a root site collection with the MySites Template. I have run the UPSA and synched all the users from the AD.

When i enter mysistes directly trough its link, or via my portal webapp, I have to sign in, which is okay. But I cannot sign in with any of my user accounts, they just does not get recognized.

---New Informaiton

I found this http://blog.solutions2share.net/2013/01/cant-login-to-sharepoint-2013-site-when.html guide. After i do the last steps and iisreset, I am able to log-in. But why is this necessary, and I am doing this on a virtual machine, will this be applied to all clients ?

Comment: did you turn on self service-site creation on the web application?

Comment: Yes, i did enable the self service-site creation,

Comment: You should add your update as an answer, that way you will be able to correctly resolve this question

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so mysites, when mapped the proper way in the DNS, works from client computers, but not from the server. So for the mysites to work on the server one must follow the guide from below.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861/en-us